# Generate large matrix filled with 0's or 1's in R

Tags: r, matrix

In R language, I am trying to generate a large matrix filled with `0`'s and `1`'s.

I have generated a large matrix but its filled with values **between** 0 and 1.

Here is how I did that:

```
NCols=500 
NRows=700 
mr<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols)
```

Comment: It's a good idea to reduce your problem to the smallest piece you can't figure out.  In this case the matrix stuff has nothing to do with the problem.  Your issue boils down to "How do I randomly generate 0s and 1s"

Comment: You could do `as.integer(mr > 0.5)`.

Comment: You should really read [this](http://www.quantumforest.com/2012/08/m-x-n-matrix-with-randomly-assigned-01/). Different methods are described and compared.

Comment: @gnat (aka Oleg Ignatenko), he stalks me on SO and downvotes all my questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are asking how to generate a matrix with just zero and 1

Here is how I would do it

```
onezero <- function(nrow,ncol)
  matrix(sample(c(0,1), replace=T, size=nrow*ncol), nrow=nrow)
```

With `nrow` and `ncol` the rows and columns of the matrix

```
R> onezero(5,5)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    0    1    0
[2,]    1    1    1    1    0
[3,]    1    1    0    0    0
[4,]    1    0    0    1    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rbinom`too. And can change the probability of success on each trial. In this case, it's .5.

```
nrow<-700
ncol<-500
mat01 <- matrix(rbinom(nrow*ncol,1,.5),nrow,ncol)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> number.of.columns = 5
> number.of.rows = 10
> matrix.size = number.of.columns*number.of.rows
> ones.and.zeros.samples = sample(0:1, matrix.size, replace=TRUE)
> A = matrix(ones.and.zeros.samples, number.of.rows) 
> A
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]                                             
 [1,]    0    0    0    1    1                                             
 [2,]    1    0    0    0    1                                             
 [3,]    0    1    1    0    0                                             
 [4,]    0    0    1    1    1                                             
 [5,]    1    0    1    1    0                                             
 [6,]    0    1    0    1    1                                             
 [7,]    0    0    1    1    0                                             
 [8,]    0    1    0    0    0                                             
 [9,]    0    0    0    0    0                                             
[10,]    0    0    0    1    1
```

Comment: I didn't down-vote this, but surely you see that your answer is not correct as presented....

Comment: Hmm.. As far as I can tell, this exemplifies the solution to the question asked.  What am I missing?

Comment: The distinction between rows and columns perhaps?